# SwiftUI content is not displayed on top of the screen

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I have a `NavigationView` and then a `VStack`. The issue is that everything inside `VStack` is being displayed in the middle of the screen and not on top. Why is that?

```
var body: some View {
    VStack {
        VStack(alignment: .leading) {

            if (request?.receiverID ?? "") == userDataViewModel.userID {
                Text("\(sendertFirstName) wants to ship your package").font(.title)
            } else {
                Text("You want to ship \(recieverFirstName)'s package").font(.title)
            }

            HStack{
                Image(systemName: "clock.fill").font(.subheadline)
                Text("\(createdAt, formatter: DateService().shortTime)").font(.subheadline).foregroundColor(.secondary)
            }

            HStack {
                VStack(alignment: .leading) {
                    HStack {
                        Image(systemName: "person.fill").font(.subheadline)
                        Text(sendertFirstName).font(.subheadline).foregroundColor(.secondary)
                    }
                }

                Spacer()

                VStack(alignment: .leading) {
                    HStack {
                        Image(systemName: "star.fill")
                        Text(rating).font(.subheadline).foregroundColor(.secondary)
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        VStack(alignment: .center) {
            HStack {
                Button("Accept") {
                    //print(self.request.createdAt)
                    //FirestoreService().respondToRequest(request: self.request.documentReference, status: "accepted")
                }
                .padding()
                Button("Decline") {
                    //FirestoreService().respondToRequest(request: self.request.documentReference, status: "declined")
                }
                .foregroundColor(.red)
                .padding()
            }
        }

        ScrollView {
            ForEach(messages) { (message: Message) in
                if message.senderId == self.userDataViewModel.userID {
                    HStack {
                        Spacer()
                        Text(message.text).font(.subheadline).padding(7.5).background(self.blue).cornerRadius(30).foregroundColor(.white)
                    }.padding(.bottom, 2)
                } else {
                    HStack {
                        Text(message.text).font(.subheadline).padding(7.5).background(self.gray).cornerRadius(30).foregroundColor(.white)
                        Spacer()
                    }.padding(.bottom, 2)
                }

            }
        }

        HStack {
            TextField("Message", text: $inputMessage).padding(5).background(self.gray).cornerRadius(30).foregroundColor(.white)

            Button(action: {
                let msg: [String: Any] = [
                    "text": self.inputMessage,
                    "createdAt": Timestamp(),
                    "senderId": self.userDataViewModel.userID
                ]

                self.reference.updateData([
                    "messages": FieldValue.arrayUnion([msg])
                ])

                self.messages.append(Message(dictionary: msg))

                self.inputMessage = ""

            }) {
                Image(systemName: "arrow.up.circle.fill").foregroundColor(self.blue).font(.title)
            }
        }
        Spacer()
    }
    .padding()
    .border(Color.red)
}
```

I want the content to start on top not on the middle. What am I doing wrong here?

[image]

Comment: Are you saying the content inside the VStack is centred, or the VStack is centred within the screen?

Comment: everything is centred so I assume the `VStack`

Comment: Can you show where your VStack is? Just add a `.border(Color.red)` to the VStack so it is easy to see. Then I can see if you need a `Spacer()`, or something else.

Comment: yes the Vstack is in the middle. I added a spacer but it didnt do anything. check the updated screenshot

Comment: Something else is happening. Can you share more code? It would really help

Comment: check the updated question @George_E

Comment: Upon using your code (replacing your variables with hard-coded values), I could not reproduce your issue. Are you sure that is _all_ your code?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/204274/discussion-between-george-e-and-rexhin-hoxha).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You don't need the `NavigationView` - the way you have everything set up now you are wrapping the `VStack` in a `NavigationView` twice and the massive white space is the second empty navigation bar.

By default most `View`s take only the amount of space they need and they are placed in the center of their parent view. So if you want your content to be placed at the top, you need to add `Spacer()` as the last element in your `VStack`:

```
var body: some View {
    VStack {
        /* ... */
        Spacer()
    }
}
```

`Spacer` is one of the rare `View`s that takes all space offered to it by the parent view and will push all of your content upwards.

Comment: I removed the NavigationView. Still the same

Comment: And added the `Spacer()`?

Comment: Based on your edited question the Spacer() needs to go above the bottom message view, possibly inside the `ScrollView`

Comment: Adding the Spacer inside ScrollView doesn't change a thing but After I added the Spacer at the end of VStack and removed padding() the content moved on the top but it's still not at the very top. I updarted the image

Comment: I had a look in the view debugger and it looks like there is still a large navigation bar present. You should add `.navigationBarTitle("", displayMode: .inline)` as the last element inside your body and the gap will go away

Comment: that worked. so the title bar is present always and by default is big right?

Comment: The bar is present unless you hide it - it should only be large on the first screen by default. In my opinion this not expected behaviour.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can try this way:

```
   NavigationView {
    VStack {
        ...
    }.frame(maxHeight:.infinity,  alignment: .top)
      .padding()
.border(Color.red).navigationBarTitle("", displayMode: .inline)
   }
```

Comment: It seems you have multiple   NavigationViews in the outer views. Basically please use one  NavigationView in all swiftUI

Comment: I removed the NavigationView. Still the same

Comment: The navagation bar is in largeTitle mode, you need to use .inline as above.

Answer (score 0):

Add a `.navigationBarHidden(true)` to your `VStack`